# Как указать определённое имя класса для поиска в BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

На сайте имеются такие теги на одном уровне:

```html
<tr class="tr-wrap">
  <td class="td-text td-text_bold">RU</td>
  <td class="td-text">800.00 руб.</td>
  <td class="td-text">990.00  руб.</td>
</tr>

<tr class="tr-wrap">
  <td class="td-text td-text_bold">BY</td>
  <td class="td-text">600.00 руб.</td>
  <td class="td-text">49.00 бел.руб.</td>
</tr>

<tr class="tr-wrap">
  <td class="td-text td-text_bold">AM</td>
  <td class="td-text">650.00 руб.</td>
  <td class="td-text">11990.00 драм</td>
</tr>
```

Как `BeautifulSoup` указать определённое имя класса `td-text`, не включающее в себя `td-text td-text_bold`?

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему так. Заменил класс `td-text td-text_bold`, который "мешал" мне парсить теги с классом `td-text`, на другой, а именно на класс `td-text_bold`:

```
html = '''
<tr class="tr-wrap">
  <td class="td-text td-text_bold">RU</td>
  <td class="td-text">800.00 руб.</td>
  <td class="td-text">990.00  руб.</td>
</tr>

<tr class="tr-wrap">
  <td class="td-text td-text_bold">BY</td>
  <td class="td-text">600.00 руб.</td>
  <td class="td-text">49.00 бел.руб.</td>
</tr>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for td in soup.find_all('td', {'class':'td-text td-text_bold'}):
    td.attrs['class'] = ['td-text_bold']
```

Comment: 1) А зачем? 2) А как это на вопрос ответит? 3) Чем мешал 'td-text td-text_bold' если можно было просто по td-text_bold или td-text обращаться (в моем ответе есть этому пример)?

Comment: @gil9red нет, вы поняли всё правильно, просто я догадался до того, что написал в ответе, до вашего ответа, и использовал такой вариант. В любом случае результат получается одинаковый.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('a.html', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as a:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(a, 'html.parser')
    results = soup.findAll("td", { "class" : "td-text" })

    for result in results :
            if len(result['class']) == 1:
                print(result)
```

---

Или компактнее, с помощью  lambda-функции

```
result = soup.findAll(
            lambda tag:tag.name == "td" and
            len(tag["class"]) == 1)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить элементы, содержащие только класс `td-text`, можно воспользоваться css-селектором `td[class=td-text]`:

```py
html = '''
<tr class="tr-wrap">
  <td class="td-text td-text_bold">RU</td>
  <td class="td-text">800.00 руб.</td>
  <td class="td-text">990.00  руб.</td>
</tr>

<tr class="tr-wrap">
  <td class="td-text td-text_bold">BY</td>
  <td class="td-text">600.00 руб.</td>
  <td class="td-text">49.00 бел.руб.</td>
</tr>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
root = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
td_list = root.select('td[class=td-text]')
print([td.text for td in td_list])
```

Результат:

```
['800.00 руб.', '990.00  руб.', '600.00 руб.', '49.00 бел.руб.']
```

---

**UPD.** Похоже, я неправильно понял что хочет автор.

Вот решение для изменения атрибута `class` у определенных тегов:

```
td_list = root.select('.td-text.td-text_bold')
print(td_list)

for td in td_list:
    td['class'] = 'td-text'

print(td_list)
```

Результат:

```
[<td class="td-text td-text_bold">RU</td>, <td class="td-text td-text_bold">BY</td>]
[<td class="td-text">RU</td>, <td class="td-text">BY</td>]
```